# Create new instances in AWS Elastic Beanstalk programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scale, scalability, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I am trying to understand it by reading the documentation and developing from it. As my reading was growing, I came up with the following question: is it possible to scale up or down an application by its source code? For instance, if my application reaches some threshold, it must scale up.

I have researched about it but could not find any code that does that and the only way that I found to scale an application is to increase or decrease its instances by AWS Elastic Beanstalk console.

Can anyone help me to confirm if there is a way to do it programmatically, or the only way to scale up and down is by doing it by the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk just creates some AWS resources for you. Those resources include an EC2 AutoScaling Group. You would modify the desired instance count attribute of the AutoScaling group in order to trigger a scaling event. You can do this in any of the AWS SDKs for the different programming languages.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will take a look on it

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Elastic Beanstalk does have a public API to let you perform operations by using code. For example, here is the Javadocs for the Java API for this service.

[Interface ElasticBeanstalkClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/services/elasticbeanstalk/ElasticBeanstalkClient.html)

There are certain things you can modify. For example, read the updateApplicationVersion method. However, you need to read these Javadocs to figure out what is possible and what is not possible.

Because there are no public examples (yet) for this API, here is a functioning example that describes using this API to describe deployed apps.

```
package com.aws.example;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.ApplicationDescription;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeApplicationsResponse;

import java.util.List;

public class DescribeApplications {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        ElasticBeanstalkClient beanstalkClient = ElasticBeanstalkClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        DescribeApplicationsResponse applicationsResponse = beanstalkClient.describeApplications();
        List<ApplicationDescription> apps = applicationsResponse.applications();
        for (ApplicationDescription app: apps) {
            System.out.println("The application name is "+app.applicationName());
            System.out.println("The application ARN  is "+app.applicationArn());
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello smac2020, thanks for your reply, I will read this JavaDoc!

Comment: The method createApplication looks interesting.